# What is the difference between "give something to someone" and "give something away to someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *give something to someone* and *give something away to someone* in the sense giving that thing for free or as a present? For example:

> I'm going to **give** the phone to Kate. I don't use it anyway.
>
> I'm going to **give** the phone **away** to Kate. I don't use it
> anyway.

Comment: [If you give away something that you own, you give it to someone, rather than selling it, often because you no longer want it.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/give-away)

Comment: @ ColleenV - That's useful. Note that not a single example in that link uses "give away ***to*** someone"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm going to give the phone to Kate. I don't use it anyway.
>
> I'm going to give the phone away to Kate. I don't use it anyway.

**"give" needs a direct *and* and indirect object.**

*I'm going to give to Kate.* (incorrect)

*I'm going to give the phone.* (incorrect)

---

**"give away" only needs a direct object.**

*I'm going to give the phone away.* (correct)

I personally would never use "give away" with an indirect object.

*I'm going to give the phone away to Kate.* (incorrect in my opinion)

---

Note that if you give something *away*, you usually have not decided to whom you will give it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you *give away* something that already belongs to you. *Give* on its own could refer to something you have just bought as a present for someone.

Answer (score 0):

"Give" is much broader in scope.  You can give things that you do not own -- a child passing out milk in class is giving the other children milk, but not giving it away -- and give them to be a temporary loan -- one man could give another his car for a trip, to be returned on his return, not giving it away.

Answer (score 0):

To *give something away* can mean to (usually inadvertently) reveal a secret or clandestine activity, e.g. someone involved in a practical joke, organisation of a surprise party or execution of a heist might accidentally mention it within earshot of victim, birthday boy/girl/person or the police.

So, the meaning can differ. Context will usually distinguish the intended meaning.

In general the meaning is similar although giving *away* strongly implies *as a gift*, whereas simply giving could be an obligation, part of a trade or repayment of a debt; a loan (or return of one); handing an item to an intermediary for delivery... and so on.